# The type jakarta.servlet.ServletContext cannot be resolved

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-migration

I am having this problem on the beginning of my learning Spring Web project. I am following a course and I am still having the problem.
I am trying all the hints found here on StackOverflow, but no one is solving the issue. This is the error:
[image]

And this is the pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>it.corsospring.web</groupId>
<artifactId>corsospringweb</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>corsospringweb</name>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

How can I resolve it? Thank you very much!

Comment: Spring 6 is using JakartaEE **not** JavaEE. You should include the `jakarta.servlet-api` dependency version 5 or up instead of the `javax.servlet-api` dependency. So in short use https://search.maven.org/artifact/jakarta.servlet/jakarta.servlet-api/6.0.0/jar as a dependency instead of `javax.servlet-api`.

Comment: You are my savior!!! I did not know it, I am a new learner and I was just following this course. Now it is working, thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that [Oracle Corp](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_Corporation) donated *Java EE* technologies to the [Eclipse Foundation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_Foundation), where they became [*Jakarta EE*](https://jakarta.ee/). See [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_EE).

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75445639/the-type-jakarta-servlet-servletcontext-cannot-be-resolved/75446313#comment133117818_75445639), you are using Spring 6 which relies on Jakarta EE 9. Jakarta EE 9 supports Servlet 5 specification. You can actually use [Jakarta EE 9.1](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9.1/) as [the only change](https://jakartaee.github.io/platform/jakartaee9/JakartaEE9.1) from 9.0 is support for Java 11.

And Spring 6 requires Java 17+. Read:

- [*What's New in Version 6.0*](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/What%27s-New-in-Spring-Framework-6.x#whats-new-in-version-60)
- [*Upgrading to Version 6*](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-6.x#upgrading-to-version-60)

Your POM fails to respect these requirements.

- You use Java EE rather than [Jakarta EE](https://jakarta.ee/). You should be using `jakarta.*` packages rather than `javax.*`.
- You specify Servlet 4 rather than [Servlet 5](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/).
- You call for Java 8 rather than Java 17 or later.

Answer (score -1):

Downgrade your Spring Version from 6.0.3 --> 5.3.4